# Change css of static class with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the css rules on a class called `active` which have static css already but i would like to alter a rule in it to make an div animate slide. i don´t know how to target a class instead of an element with the name of the class.

Javascript

```
var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
active.style.color = 'red';
```

I´ve tried both these methods but none seems to work.

```
var i = 0;
    while(i < divs.length) {
        if(divs[i].className == "active") {
            var b = 0;
            for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++){
                divs[i].style.left = b+'em';
                b += 6;

            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

I´t wont add left to the css rule nor color.

CSS

```
.active{
position:absolute;
left:-60em;
```

Jquery is not an option in this case.

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your necessary code, there could be multiple problems in the code?

Comment: I want to grab the class name "active" and change the left rule to 60em with Javascript.